# Chrome DevTools Protocol: Waterfall graph

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

Is it possible to acquire the data from the waterfall graph in the network tab in Chrome DevTools through the Chrome DevTools Protocol? If so, how do I do it?

Comment: Please clerify what `acquire` means to you? Acces thos data using JavaScript from within the loaded web page? Or Exprt to a file? Or ...?

Comment: I want to get the graph using the DevTools Protocol, meaning I want to start a headless chrome, open a page and save the data from the graph in, for example, JSON. I'm trying to make a python program that does this automatically.